# блокировка анимации выпадающей панели

Tags: jquery

подскажите пожалуйста почему на [этой странице](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/jq_menu/) не работает блокировка анимации выпадающих пунктов меню. вот jq-код для тех кому лень открывать живой пример

```
            $(document).ready(function(){       
            //анимация левого меню - начало
            var menu = $('#left_menu');
            var menu_punkt = $('#left_menu>ul>li');
            var content = $('#content');
            var running = false;

            menu.css('left', '-200px');
            content.css('margin-left', '23px');

            menu.on({
                'mouseenter': showF,
                'mouseleave': hideF
            });

            function showF(){
                menu.stop().animate({
                    left: '0px'
                }, 'normal', 'swing');

                content.stop().animate({
                    marginLeft: '223px'
                }, 'normal', 'swing');
            }

            function hideF(){                       
                menu.stop().animate({
                    left: '-200px'
                }, 'fast', 'swing');

                content.stop().animate({
                    marginLeft: '23px'
                }, 'fast', 'swing');                    
            }

            menu_punkt.on({
                'mouseenter': show_deepF,
                'mouseleave': hide_deepF
            });

            function show_deepF(){
                if(running == false){
                    running = true;

                    $(this).find('ul').slideDown('fast');

                    running = false;
                }
            }

            function hide_deepF(){
                if(running == false){
                    running = true;

                    $(this).find('ul').slideUp('fast');

                    running = false;
                }                   
            }               
            //анимация левого меню - конец
        })
```

то есть проблема в том, что если беспорядочно поводить курсором по области пунктов меню, то анимация становится неконтролируемой на определенное время

Comment: останавливайте анимацию перед тем, как запустить новую.

Comment: я понял. а как?

Comment: Перед **.slideDown()** и **.slideUp()** так же ставьте **.stop()**, как и перед **.animate()**

Comment: .stop() останавливает её совсем(

Comment: Значит смотрите в сторону [.queue()](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%9E%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: спасибо, попробую. но способ, который я применил, он классический. но почему то не срабатывает


                if(running == false){
                    running = true;

                    /////

                    running = false;
                }

Comment: Потому что `running = false;` нужно выполнять после завершения анимации, в колбек вынесите её.

    if(running) return;
          
    $(this).find('ul').slideUp('fast', function() {
     running = false;
    });

Comment: пробовал. вот результат, если интересно http://prozaik.16mb.com/js/jq_menu2/

Comment: Я одно не могу понять - почему у вас анимацию, как вы сказали ".stop() останавливает её совсем"? Я этого что-то [не могу заметить](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/SGcZL/).

Comment: @Deonis видимо он имел ввиду, что высота начинает глючить у ul элементов. Наверно из-за более старой версии библиотеки.